# Extract part of char array as char*

Tags: c++

From this:

`"16;foo;interesting-text"`

which is a `char[]` I want to extract few parts. I've already managed how to extract `16` as int, `foo` as `string`, but I have problem with extracting `interesting-text` as pointer to `char*`.

This is how its done right now:

```
"16;foo;bar;interesting-text"
//dataLen contains 16
//foundSecondComma is index of second semicolon occurence

char* messageData = new char[dataLen+1];
memcpy(messageData, buffer+foundSecondComma+1, dataLen);
//messageData contains 'interesting-text' and few unnecessary characters

string extractedData(messageData, dataLen);

//do stuff with messageData

delete messageData;
```

After that `messageData` contains `interesting-text` and some unnecesasry characters. I can convert this to string (`extractedData`), but I really need `char *`. How can I do that properly?

Comment: You already seem to perfectly understand that you can construct a `std::string` by passing a pointer to the first character, and the number of characters. So, what exactly do you expect to accomplish by, first, copying the given number of characters to a `new` buffer? What exactly is that going to do that simply `string extractedData(buffer+foundSecondComma+1, dataLen)` does not do?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I would just like to know where I make mistake.

Comment: Maybe you just forget to insert a '\0' at the end of your C-style string?

Answer (score 0):

What about copying it out again?

```
std::size_t len = extractedData.size() + 1;
char *want = new char[len];
strncpy(want, extractedData.c_str(), len);
```

Now you have `want` as what you want.